# SAS: keep non-missing values from an array

Tags: arrays, sas, do-loops

I have a dataset with date1-date99 and there are at most 5 non-missing dates per observation. I want to only keep the non-missing dates and assign them to datenew1-datenew5.  Any suggestions on the best way to to do this.  I thought of doing and do loop within another do loop (i=1 to 5 and j=1 to 99), but I couldn't remember the best way to move to the next value of i once the first non-missing date had been found.

Comment: Do you need the non-missing dates to be in any particular order in the new array?

Comment: Yes, I need the order to remain what it was in the original data.  For example, in the original: date1 = 1Jan1980, date2=., date3=5Feb1980, and I want the new dataset to have datenew1 = 1Jan1980, datenew2=5Feb1980. Thanks.

Comment: Are the dates in ascending order in the original dataset?

Comment: The order isn't necessarily ascending.  They are in order based on another variable (sequence number).  The sequence number is used to assign the number to the date variable.  In the example above, 1Jan1980 is from sequencenumber=1, 5Feb1980 is from sequencenumber=3.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it:

```
data have;
informat total_nonmissing;
do j = 1 to 1000; /*Number of rows to output*/
    array date[99];
    chosen = 0;
    remaining = dim(date);
    do i = 1 to remaining;
        call missing(date[i]);
        if ranuni(2) < (5-chosen) / remaining then do;
            date[i] = round(ranuni(1)*10000);
            chosen + 1;
            remaining + (-1);               
        end;
    end;
    total_nonmissing = n(of date{*});
    format date: yymmdd10.;
    output;
    drop i j chosen remaining;
end;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    array newdate[5];
    array date[99];
    j = 1;
    do i = 1 to dim(date);
        if not(missing(date[i])) then do;
            newdate[j] = date[i];
            j + 1;
        end;
    end;
    format newdate: yymmdd10.;
    keep newdate:;
run;
```

Comment: One of the nice features of SAS do loops is that you have have compound  conditions.  So you could prevent array index errors by changing the do loop to;  `do i=1 to dim(date) while (j<=dim(newdate));`  This would make it stop looking for dates when NEWDATE array is filled.